# Need dialer with call transfer after answer

Tags: twilio

I'm looking for a twimlet or php script for the Twilio API that would implement an outbound calling list function with optional transfer to recorded message -

1. Sales person Clicks number in a list to dial outbound call
2. dialed party answers
3. Sales person realizes it's a machine and clicks a link to transfer the call to a recorded message that will be left on the machine.
4. Or, if it's not a machine sales person proceeds with the call.

Is something like that available already canned or scripted?

Comment: The path I'm on is to start with this "click to call" functionality: https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call , and add the call transfer function using the "call redirect" endpoint: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state .

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.

Not sure I've seen anything out of the box to do this but it would not be hard to create and it sounds like you are going down the right path with those two examples.  If you run into questions, feel free to post them on SO or contact our support team using help@twilio.com

Answer (score 0):

Since the initial ask we've updated the [click-to-call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/php/laravel#0) solution in a code complete tutorial.

In the last step, after a call is connected and Twilio asks for TwiML instructions you might consider adapting from the [call screening tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/php/laravel#5)  to handle voicemail:

```
public function agentVoicemail(Request $request, $agentId)
{
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml;
    $callStatus = $request->input('DialCallStatus');

    if ($callStatus !== 'completed') {
        $response->say(
            'It appears that no agent is available. ' .
            'Please leave a message after the beep',
            ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
        );

        $response->record(
            ['maxLength' => '20',
             'method' => 'GET',
             'action' => route('hangup', [], false),
             'transcribeCallback' => route(
                 'store-recording', ['agent' => $agentId], false
             )
            ]
        );

        $response->say(
            'No recording received. Goodbye',
            ['voice' => 'alice', 'language' => 'en-GB']
        );
        $response->hangup();

        return $response;
    }

    return "Ok";
}
```